# Firefox Force High Contrast Mode on i3

Tags: firefox, i3-window-manager

So typically, firefox automatically recognizes if your OS (windows/linux) has a high contrast theme enabled. I am currently using i3 window manager on linux which does not have theme customization in the normal desktop sense. Is there a manual way to enable this mode while still using i3?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/183564/high-contrast-theme-firefox-problem

Comment: Same question but most of the solutions are work-arounds. Still wondering if there is a direct way since firefox supports such behavior.